# how to create buttons to change page content in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, button

I am building a Ruby on Rails web application and I use bootstrapUI for the view of my application.

I want to create 4 buttons in my index page and when I click in each one of them then the content of the page should change accordingly. (for now the content is static so it is not necessary to make it dynamic although it would be nice)

I suppose that I somehow need to use jquery but I don't know exactly how to start.

Do you have to suggest any tutorial on this or how to start because I am a bit confused ?

Comment: If found that http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html is quite a nice guide to get you started with rails basics.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that javascript(jquery is easiest, IMHO) is the way to go for this behavior.  Check out the Rails Tutorial section about ajax(asynchronous javascript) [here.](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax)

The basic idea is this:

1. You push a button that sends a request to your rails server.
2. Your rails server sees that it is an ajax request and returns the desired data back to the client
3. Your client is awaiting the response so once it received the data back from the server you can add the data to the existing page.

As far as implementation, I would start with the rails guide I posted then check out the jquery ajax documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  Another great resource is the rails guide that deals with ajax which can be found [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).